# How to redirect links in email template to salesforce1 app

Tags: apex, mobile, salesforce1-app, chatter-mobile

With the new salesforce1 app which looks cool, i am currently not able to click a record link and open the record in salesforce1. I am using Ipad and set all the salesforce1 setting from the salesforce1 documentation: 
"For the mobile browser app, from Setup, click Mobile Administration > Salesforce1. Select
Enable the Salesforce mobile browser app to turn on automatic redirection to
the mobile browser app whenever a user logs into Salesforce using a supported mobile browser."

But when i click a link its still going into the safari browser and not the Salesforce1 app. Is there something missing? thanks a lot.

Comment: If you don't want to use the browser, install the app and run it to access records.  Note that in the browser, users have a choice to run the full site and then need to use a link like below (but with correct instance) to get the Salesforce1 interface in the browser window: https://naXX.salesforce.com/one/one.app

Comment: I can't find the reference for this, but I though you could use Chatter://XXX as the link to open up the record in the app on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the issue where the Detail Link in the email template was just taking me to the contact summary on SF1. In using the link from RichClark it worked for me. I just changed it to point to the contact detail page like this...

```
com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId={!Contact.Id}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can place links in email templates that navigate to the Salesforce1 app in the following format:

```
com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId={Account.Id}
```

I suggest you put that in alongside the standard `{Account.Link}` and give users a choice.

e.g.

To view this record please select either:
`{Account.Link}` to view this in your browser
`com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId={Account.Id}` to open in Salesforce1*

Answer (score 1):

From the wording of the documentation, it sounds like that setting will only redirect users from a mobile browser to the Salesforce1 mobile app. Any custom links or URL fields you click within the Salesforce1 app would still go to a mobile browser.

Where are you first clicking on the Salesforce record link?

Comment: I have a email template that has the record detail link with it. Like 'https://ap1.salesforce.com/50090000004rvhrAAA' is a link that is displayed in the email and when i click on the link in ipad i go to the safari browser rather than Salesforce1 app. I need the link to be redirected to salesforce1 app when viewed in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://naXX.salesforce.com/one/one.app
Where the XX is replaced by your instance.

Comment: but the link is the record detail link which is part of the email template. How can put a detail link of a record here, i see the you pasted just opens the salesforce1 app.

Comment: You can try visiting the page on the Salesforce1 browser and copying the huge link into your email template or into a field on the record.  But I don't know of a way to generate the link dynamically, so hopefully you have a small set of records you would need to do this for!  I think the record ID will be the last 36 characters or so.

Comment: Here are two unsupported link options: 

To view a record:
com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId=yourRecordID

To edit it (if you have permissions)
com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/edit?entityId=yourRecordID

Note that these aren't officially supported, but that deep links may be on the S1 roadmap according to a post on success.salesforce.com